# Django: form with fields for creating related objects

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have several models similar to these (example from Django docs):

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

And I have HTML form in which (if we continue the analogy with the example from the docs) there are three separate input fields for:

- entering the `name` of the `Person`;
- specifying the `date_joined`;
- specifying the `invite_reason`

And button "Add member".
The user fills in all these fields and clicks on this button. JS code adds hidden input fields (filled in with the entered values) to the html page (so that all entered data will be included in the POST-request data). And also JS adds an span-element to the page with information about the added member with a button "Delete" next to it. Then three visible fields are cleared so that you can enter data for the next person. It looks like this:

[image]

Now I see two ways to handle this situation on the Django side:

1. Put all the logic for working with memberships in the form:

> ```
> class MembershipForm(forms.ModelForm):
>     class Meta:
>         model = Membership
>         fields = ('person', 'date_joined', 'invite_reason')
>
>
> class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
>     class Meta:
>         model = Recipe
>         fields = ('name',)
>
>     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
>         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>         self.memberships = self.instance.membership_set.all()
>
>     def clean(self):
>         super().clean()
>         self.memberships = []
>
>         memberships_data = self.get_memberships_data(self.data) 
>         for name, date_joined, invite_reason in memberships_data:
>             data = {
>                 'person': name,
>                 'date_joined': date_joined,
>                 'invite_reason': invite_reason
>             }
>             membership_form = MembershipForm(data)
>             if membership_form.is_valid():
>                 self.memberships.append(membership_form.instance)
>             else:
>                 membership_errors = sum(membership_form.errors.values(), [])
>                 self.add_error(None, membership_errors)
>
>         # There may be other checks here as well. 
>         # For example, checks for the presence of at least one group member
>
>     def _save_m2m(self):
>         super()._save_m2m()
>         self.instance.members.clear()
>         self.instance.membership_set.set(self.memberships, bulk=False)
> ```

2. Use `inlineformset_factory` (example for CreateView)

> ```
> MembershipFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(Group, Membership, fields=('person', 'date_joined', 'invite_reason'))
>
> class CreateGroupView(CreateView):
>     model = Group
>     ...
>
>     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         self.object = None
>         form_class = self.get_form_class()
>         form = self.get_form(form_class)
>         membership_formset = MembershipFormSet()
>         return self.render_to_response(
>             self.get_context_data(
>                 form=form,
>                 membership_formset=membership_formset
>             )
>         )
>
>     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         self.object = None
>         form_class = self.get_form_class()
>         form = self.get_form(form_class)
>         membership_formset = MembershipFormSet(self.request.POST)
>         if (form.is_valid() and membership_formset.is_valid()):
>             return self.form_valid(form, membership_formset)
>         else:
>             return self.form_invalid(form, membership_formset)
>
>     def form_valid(self, form, membership_formset):
>         self.object = form.save(commit=False)
>         self.object.author = self.request.user
>         self.object.save()
>         membership_formset.instance = self.object
>         membership_formset.save()
>         return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
>
>     def form_invalid(self, form, membership_formset):
>         return self.render_to_response(
>             self.get_context_data(
>                 form=form,
>                 membership_formset=membership_formset
>             )
>         )
> ```

In this case, all the logic for processing forms will be in view-functions (or View classes). Also, this approach assumes a certain format of hidden input fields, which allows the formset to retrieve data without additional settings. And it imposes additional restrictions on the js code (in terms of removing items from the list). However, this approach seems like a cleaner solution to me.

I would like to hear the opinion of experienced developers which approach would be most suitable here. Or both the first and the second are bad, but may be there is another, more appropriate for this situation.

If the problem is not clear, I am ready to answer any clarifying questions

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

inlineformset_factory() is a better solution ,also I suggest, use function based view instead of class based view, your code will be much shorter and easier to maintain.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I already thought that in a week so no one will say anything :)

Comment: what disadvantages do you see in the first method?

Comment: the first 4 lines of both GET and POST are same , this is against the DRY principle of Django. plus shorter code is much easier to maintain.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about CBV vs FBV. I agree that in this case it is better to use FBV. But I talk about rewriting the 'clean' method in the form so that it extracts the data of new members from the request data and stores them in an internal attribute. How is this done in my example #1